# With Spring Boot 2.2+, how can you create a bean when the application is NOT running on a Cloud Platform

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Boot 2.2 there is an annotation `@ConditionalOnCloudPlatform` which can be used to detect whether the application is running on a Cloud Platform.

I have the reverse issue - I want to not run a bean which is running on a Cloud Platform. For example, I have code which I don't want to run when running on Kubernetes (as the platform where I run Kubernetes already supplies the functions in the given bean).

What's the best approach to do this? I feel like I need a `@ConditionalOnCloudPlatform` annotation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@ ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) with the name of Kubernetes bean of [`@ ConditionalOnMissingClass`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingClass.html) with one of bean's (or related) classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

It seems you are using `Spring Cloud Kubernetes`. If so, when an application runs as a pod inside Kubernetes a Spring profile named 'kubernetes' is automatically get activated.

```
@Component
@Profile("!kubernetes")
public class MyLocalTestBean {}
```

**Solution 2**

Invert condition using [NonNestedConditions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/NoneNestedConditions.java) (the code below is not verified)

```
class ConditionalOnNotInCloud extends NoneNestedConditions {

    ConditionalOnNotInCloud() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION);
    }

    @ConditionalOnCloudPlatform
    static class OnCloudCondition {
    }
}

@Bean
@Conditional(ConditionalOnNotInCloud.class)
public StubBean createStubBean() {}
```

Comment: I'm actually using Azure AKS service - does that make a different to Solution 1?